# Прокси сервер на Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, proxy, tunnel

Скрипт с помощью `pytun` "ловит" все подключения и отправляет их прокси серверу. Сервер принимает их исполняет, отправляя данные обратно.

Код:

```py
from pytun import TunTapDevice

tun = TunTapDevice(name='proxy')
tun.addr = '10.8.0.1'
tun.dstaddr = '10.8.0.2'
tun.netmask = '255.255.255.0'
tun.mtu = 1500
tun.up()

def listen()
    while True:
        read = tun.read(tun.mtu)
        send(read)

def recieve(data):
    tun.write(plaindata)
```

Код упрощен, полная версия на https://pastebin.com/vKVYtsbT

Проблема в том, что сервер не отдаёт подключения, только принимает их.

Разрабатываю альтернативу https://github.com/PiMaker/Teletun (IP over Telegram) т.к. у меня не установился telegram-cli.